# [Synfony2]MopaBootstrapBundle use jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I installed MopeBootstrap for use Bootsrap with my symfony project. For the moment i want to test some bootstrap components.

I have:

```
{# src/My/MyBundle/Ressources/views/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends "MopaBootstrapBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I was thinking i could use bootstrap like this but it doesn't work.

How can i use MopaBootrap with Jumbotron or other bootstrap's components.

Edit: Now i have

```
{% block content %}

{% stylesheets  '@MyMyBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.css' %}
       <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}


<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In the web page's source i can open my bootstrap.css but it doesn't work ><.

I already have included twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master in composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to install cssembed-0.3.6.jar. Now it seem to work !

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't include the bootstrap.css. I guess MopaBootstrapBundle only change the html structure of your forms/fields to be compatible with Twitter Bootstrap but didn't include the bootstrap css automaticaly.
Add this in your layout.html.twig:

```
   {% stylesheets
         '@YourBundle/path/to/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'
   %}
       <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
   {% endstylesheets %}
```

PS:

> We decided not to take the twitter/bootstrap distribution into this
>   repo to seperate concerns more efficently. So you have to include
>   twitter/bootstrap in some manner into your project

https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/including-bootstrap.md

Comment: I change my code but it doesn't work. The generate HTML seem correct. If i put the <link> and my <div> in a new html page and open it with google chrome, it work. Strange ^^